# Should the 'language' tag be deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) seems like the ultimate cop-out tag. It has five questions with an accumulated score of -8, I expect it to sink further today with the question that made me stumble upon it.

There is no description or usage guide and of the five questions three are closed and today's most likely will be.

I move for the tag to be deleted. It adds no value whatsoever to the taxonomy.

Since [our mod RegDwigнt](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwig%d0%bdt) already retagged everything there are currently no more questions tagged with this tag.  Following the [guideline from Meta.SE on burninating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) I posthumously answer these to do the final burninating step.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   It wasn't. It was a bad cop-out tag.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   It was supremely meta.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   They didn't.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   They didn't.

The site is ready to get that tag
[image]

Comment: Yeah. Definitely blacklist this. And permaban whoever created it. For the time being I've manually retagged every single question with this tag. And it's not even like the OPs couldn't think of something better for lack of vocabulary or education. No, *all* of them actually *had* thought of something better. All of them used very specific terms in the body of their questions. Their not putting the exact same terms in the tags was not stupidity or laziness; it was in fact a very deliberate giant flip-off.

Comment: I've sent a message to a CM, requesting a blacklisting.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен: Done. Like a hypothetical [tag:english], [tag:language] seems intrinsic to every question on the site.

Comment: Thanks, @JonEricson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've sent a message to a CM, requesting a blacklisting. – Matt E. Эллен♦
>
> Done. Like a hypothetical [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) seems intrinsic to every question on the site. – Jon Ericson♦