# ELU tagging guideline

Tags: discussion, tags, guideline

I am suggesting to create a guideline post describing how to tag specifically for the ELU taxonomy. The discussions in chat and all the posts and comments regarding tags on meta lead me to believe that such a guideline could massively improve the state of our taxonomy going forward. If it's well accepted we might link it on the [ELU tagging page.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) Here we go.

I am suggesting to create and use a tagging guideline, offering this as a first draft. A guideline that represents the taxonomy as it is. Such a guideline can help the editors and users to choose the proper tags. Let us move discussions on the validity of single tags out of this discussion.

*I guess my question is, do you agree that a tagging guideline would be helpful for ELU?*

---

### ELU tagging guideline

**Tags for questions looking for**

- ... words, phrases, idioms, expressions. These *request questions* are our quiz or reverse dictionary questions. The appropriate tags are

  - [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) when looking for one word,
  - [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) when looking for several words and
  - [idiom-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-request) when looking for a set idiomatic expression.
- ... a decision on a *choice* between given alternatives. These *choice questions* are those which require the question to contain all alternatives. The appropriate tags are

  - [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) when deciding between *two or more given* words and
  - [expression-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-choice) when deciding between *two or more given* expressions.
  - *Those two are mutually exclusive.*
- ... explanation of meaning of *something given.* These *meaning questions* need to contain what they are asking about and sufficient context. The appropriate tags are

  - [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) for questions about nuances of words and phrases,
  - [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) for questions of understanding of parts of longer texts,
  - [phrase-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning) specifically regarding phrases and
  - [idiom-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-meaning) for idioms.
  - *Only one of those tags should be used.*
- ... clarifications about the usage of *something given.* These *usage questions* need to contain what they are asking about and an explanation what's unclear about the usage. The appropriate tags are

  - [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) for the usage of certain words and
  - [phrase-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-usage) for the usage of certain phrases.

**Tags for questions regarding**

- ... specific topics that are part of the language or linguistics. These tags can stand on their own. A multitude of our tags fall into that category, the lists are not complete.

  - They are lexical items like [nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns), [verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs), [prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions), [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms),
  - fields of linguistics like [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), [punctuation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), [pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation), [sentence-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure) ,
  - grammatical categories like [tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses), [passive-voice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice),
  - grammatical units like [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases), [clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clauses),
  - dialects and variations of English like [american-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-english), [british-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-english), [australian-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-english), [slang](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang).

The two groups above make the bulk of our tags and every question should have *at least one of those tags.* The following groups of tags offer additional information on the questions but cannot stand on their own. This is either due to the fact that they are not sufficiently able to describe a question or that they are hyponyms that should also be tagged with their hypernym tag. (Remark: I expect this last sentence to be controversial.)

**Tags describing further question information**

- ... by adding field of usage or further categorization to the question.

  - They are field of usage like [science](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science), [mathematics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), [academia](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academia),
  - time periods like [old-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-english), [middle-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-english), [1600s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1600s), [1700s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1700s),
  - source languages for translations and relations for etymology like [latin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin), [french](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french), [german](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german),
  - superfluous information like [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms), [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), [translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [antonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonym),

**Tags that refine the main question tag**

- ... by refining a popular tag. The hypernym tag should be used as well.

  - Specific tenses like [simple-past](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple-past), [present-tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/present-tense) refine [tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses).
  - Specific symbols like [comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma), [question-mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-mark) refine [punctuation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation).

**Common pitfalls**

There are some commonly misused tags even though the tag wikis describe their usage differently. Those are

- [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) vs [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality)

  - [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) describes questions regarding grammar itself
  - [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) describes questions regarding the grammaticality of sentences, clauses and the like.

**Do not create or use meta tags under any circumstances!**

- The use of meta tags is heavily discouraged on the StackExchange network. The reasoning can be found in [this blog post.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- It is also already on the [ELU tagging page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
- Bad examples of meta tags on ELU are *[words](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/blacklist-the-words-tag), [language](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9409/should-the-language-tag-be-deleted), homework ([cf. SO.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)), test, English, gre, etc..*

---

For now I'll leave it at that and wait for some feedback. Of course, this can be enhanced and refined. I think this will give our editors a fighting chance to adhere to the taxonomy as intended. After all we are editing two-thirds of all questions anyways. [Here's the query.](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/533924/675163/question-editing-percentage) If we make an easy guideline available to the people editing the questions and raise some awareness to edit the tags as well, we should be able to dramatically increase the ELU tag precision.

A second activity should be to improve the tag wikis, starting with the top 30 most used tags. I'll suggest a structure in another meta post which can then also be used as a blueprint. (EDIT 09/09/16: [Blueprint suggestion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/suggested-tag-wiki-blueprint))

Comment: What about [tag:expression-requests]? I did ask about it on meta [once](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7871/50044).

Comment: @NVZ that should in my opinion be merged with the [tag:phrase-requests] since that is referring to colloquial phrases anyways and not the grammatical ones.

Comment: I like this. The tag info should probably also be updated. *Single-word-request* and *translation* are already pretty good; perhaps the others listed here could be brought up to the same standard. Explaining the difference between *grammar* and *grammaticality* to those who don't know what *grammaticality* is is not easy!

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree, enhancing the tag wikis is a parallel task. I enhanced [tag:word-usage] recently and would suggest a similar structure for all the wikis for a high recognition value. Maybe we should provide an example structure in a meta post. In my view a tag wiki should contain an explanation what it is about, a checklist if the question fits, example questions and optionally commonly confused tags.

Comment: Of course, most of the structure is adapted from the swr tag wiki.

Comment: What, if anything, should be done about the simple "[tag:usage]" tag?

Comment: It is not a good thing to have so many word-/phrase- pairs. Most of them should be merged together.

Comment: meaning should either be banned or merged with meaning-in-context. There should be no contextless meaning questions - any such ones should be answered with dictionaries and not asked here.

Comment: @NVZ, I would like to separate the topic of _is a tagging guideline helpful_ from a discussion about specific tags.

Comment: @curiousdannii see my last comment. We should discuss single tags separately.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, we might as well try.

Some possible advantages, in my opinion:

- help users choose the right tags. (Not a big advantage, since most users will probably never see this Meta post.)
- help editors choose the right tags. (A much more significant advantage.)

Possible disadvantages:

- One more thing to keep updated in addition to the tag wikis. If it gets out-of-date, that's confusing. But people can always ask questions about it on Meta if they aren't sure if a certain part is up-to-date.

Comment: Question: do any regular contributors or high-rep users of ELU make any regular or significant use of tags? I know I don't, and their primary use on SO is to create sub-communities, which is helpful because SO is vast and the world of software is vast.

Comment: @DanBron They are useful in explicitly communicating when particular rules have to be followed. For example: if you ask a word/phrase request then you have to give sample sentence(s) with placeholders where you'd like the word to go. Rules like that can be mentioned in the tag wikis and the wikis can link to Meta discussions.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't know about others, but I don't think I've ever read a tag wiki. That may be due to being principally a mobile user, and maybe they're buried deeper in the mobile interface than the web interface. But from my experience, rules and guidelines are most commonly and most prominently communicated by high-rep users and mods commenting under questions. I doubt newbies who don't know the rules first learn them from tag wikis. Though I suppose they're a good place to record such things, if one wants an "official" place to cite.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah I wasn't thinking they would effectively inform new users, but more that they could be used to say to argumentative askers that "you have no grounds to dispute your question's closure - it's in the tag wiki". It can be hard to tell what the current policies are on Meta (there are so many posts, and the most recent may not be the most accepted, neither may the most upvoted), so tag wikis are good to record them.

Comment: @DanBron the tags wikis are abysmally underrepresented in the mobile app. That's true. In my view that's another reason to have a meta post that can be easily used as a reference for tag usage. A meta post can also be better used as a reference than tag wikis when commenting on a post.

Comment: @Helmar Thanks. I did just check, and it takes 4 clicks, one of which is unintuitive, from any given question to read the full wiki for a tag. That said, I wasn't asking so much about the utility of tag wikis as tagging in general on a site the size of ELU. We don't get enough questions on a daily basis, nor are topics here so orthogonal (as eg Java is from PHP), to have sub-communities here, which so far as I can tell, is their primary use on SO and other sites where tags get a lot of use. In my experience, the best/only? use for them here is personal blacklisting and dupe-finding.

Comment: I use tags mainly to hide certain questions from feed.

Comment: @NVZ Yeah, that's what I meant by "personal blacklisting".