# What's the best way to catch up on ELU posts after a hiatus?

Tags: discussion

I am returning to ELU after a considerable duration (~6 months). I soon realized that I have missed tons of questions and answers.

For now, I've been just going through the profiles of some of my favorite contributors to check what have they been writing. I'm also going through the moderator election related posts, which I was so looking forward to but couldn't participate! (I don't think I got any email notifs *:(* )

Thus, my questions:

- Can I filter the questions and answers for a specific duration? Like
  "show me all the top voted posts from March to August 2016."
- Is there any option to quickly collate what I've missed in these
  past 5-6 months?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, hello! Welcome back.

Comment: Good to see you, fellow south Indian. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do that.

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Search for *created:6m.. score:20 etc. is:question [favorite-tag]*

For example: [This search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A6m..+score%3A20+is%3Aquestion)

Of course, the tags only help you a bit, since tags are a mess. So support [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/proposed-elu-tagging-guideline) ;)

Comment: Wonderful! Also, I support your tag-guidelines initiative!  :)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy you're welcome, and thank you :)