# Sorting out our tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, site-cleanup

Recently, I have been going through the tag wikis of some of the less used tags, adding in definitions and basic information regarding the tag. Unfortunately, after about [page seven](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?page=7&tab=popular) of the tags, the majority have no tag wikis or excerpts.

I want to suggest that we work together as a site to sort this out.

All that needs doing for some of them is to add a quick definition of the term so that it is clearer for users.
Can people join with me to systematically work through all of the tags to add quick definitions and usage guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

I made a [blueprint](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9464/184706) a while back. It can easily be used as copy paste boilerplate. Feel free to use it when tackling the tag wikis.

Comment: That's a great help, thanks!