# Should we burninate the [spelling-checker] tag? (0 posts left tagged)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

While poking about removing the [microsoft-word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) tag from a few questions, I came across a question tagged [spelling-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling-checker).  This seemed to me to be a meta-tag of no more value than the ms-word one, so I removed it.  A quick tag search reveals that there are 60 questions with this tag.

I checked the guidelines on when to ask about tag burnination, and I *think* this one fits the bill:

- It is a meta-tag (there are many spell-checkers available (although MS Word's is the most-asked-about spell-checker here)
- it is clearly an off-topic tag (asking about spell-checking software rather than a valid ELU topic)
- it does not add any useful information  (Reviewing the list of tagged questions shows one question regarding the effect of computers on spelling (now closed) and 59 questions about (approximately) "why does the spell-checker say this is misspelled?", which is really a question about spelling, which 17 of the questions are also tagged with)

Should we burninate this tag?  Alternatively, should we make it a synonym of [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), just like [spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) is?

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the progression of the process.

Comment: Can you accept the CW answer to mark this done? I also requested a status-completed flag on the question.

Comment: The tag isn't gone yet, but I'll mark it completed if you are satisfied.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox actually it is gone. The nightly (or whenever) roomba took care of it. Unless I mistake the vanishing of the now missing information *there is no tag wiki yet, help us.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm testing a new approach to edit tracking here.

If you edit the tag out of questions just change the number. The list of questions we had in other posts seems not very helpful. Don't forget to generally tag the question correctly if you are editing. Likely candidates for these questions seem to be [punctuation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) and [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography).

When we started the tag [spelling-checker](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling-checker) was attached to 55 questions.

Now we are down to: **0**. Woo hoo!!!

**All done, now all it takes is for a mod to remove the tag itself**

Comment: All done... now what?

Comment: No, they are deleted automatically after a going unused for a period of time. See the relevant [help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Answer (score 5):

I wholeheartedly agree, full explanation in [my answer of the Word question.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9495/184706)

Regarding the further steps, I certainly advocate for *burnination*.

Synonym-mapping might not help, because modern spell checkers check more than just orthography. When it still had options in the 2013 version (burn in hell for deleting those, MS) there were about fifteen options you could check for the program to look for.

Comment: Yes, it's a meta-tag (that is, not a Meta.ELU tag, but a tag describing circumstances rather than the ELU problem itself). We should be rid of it.